# Angular or Bootstrap for responsive UI and front end validation

Tags: angular

I am developing an frontend using Angular. I want to develop a responsive front end. I have the following queries:

1. Can I develop a responsive UI using Angular alone without using responsive attributes of HTML5 and BootStrap? Or do I need to use Bootstrap and HTML5 to make my frontend responsive?
2. I know we can implement UI client side validation using Bootstrap or HTML5 and/or Angular. So while developing the front end which framework should be used for implementing validation?
3. Is there any valid reason to use Bootstrap, while developing a front end using Angular? If so, then for which functionality in particular?
4. Why is Angular development termed as a mobile first approach?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So,while developing responsive front end using Angular JS2 we need not to use Bootstrap? Or we need to use "Angular Bootstarp"? At the same do we need to use any responsive attribute for HTML? My concern is when developing using Angular JS2, if I the use of Bootstrap is unnecessary? If Angular JS2 alone can make my UI response, why I need to use Bootstrap or the responsive attributes of HTML?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can build responsive UI with pure HTML and CSS. No Angular or Bootstrap needed.

Bootstrap is a templating framework which also include multiple javascript extensions for front end development.

Angular is a structural framework meant to extend html and javascript to make front end development more dynamic.

Bootstrap and [Angular Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) makes responsive UI easy to build because they apply a set of CSS rules that are responsive by design.

2. Front-end validation is done by Javascript, not by Bootstrap or Angular.

Angular will change the way you design your front-end javascript but it is still fundamentally javascript.

3. Yes

Like explained above, Bootstrap is, first and foremost, a templating framework meant to make beautiful responsive UI easily without having to deal with writing tons of CSS or javascript to get the wanted UI. Angular is meant to make the front-end more dynamic by providing ways to manipulate data more easily. Both can be used together to provide a dynamic, responsive and beautiful front-end.

4. Where did you read that?

Angular is considered a SPA (Single page application) while bootstrap is termed as being mobile first because it focuses on making responsive UI easy to build.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.